# Accessing node name within node text braces

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am wishing for writing `$\n$` as node text, where `\n` has the node's name.

Working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [node distance=2em]
\node (0) {0};
\node (h) [above of=0] {};
\node (a) [left of=h] {$a$};
\node (b) [right of=h] {$b$};
\draw (0) -- (a);
\draw (0) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, I hope to write the description of node `a` as

```
\node (a) [left of=h] {$\n$};
```

so that I can forget about the text (but still have them in math mode).

Comment: What version of TikZ are you using?

Comment: Seems to be 3.0 (I am using texlive 2013).

Comment: In that case, I was going to suggest essentially what Ignasi wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `TikZ 3.0` you can use `node contents` and `name` options:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2em,
      mathnode/.style={name=#1, node contents=$#1$}]
\node (0) {0};
\node (h) [above of=0] {};
\node [mathnode=a, left of=h];
\node [mathnode=b, right of=h];
\draw (0) -- (a);
\draw (0) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: If you don't need it later on, you can avoid node `h`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [node distance=2em,
mathnode/.style={name=#1, node contents=$#1$}]
\node (0) {0};
\node [mathnode=a, above left= of 0];
\node [mathnode=b, above right = of 0];
\draw (0) -- (a);
\draw (0) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```